org.jruby.exceptions.TypeError: (TypeError) no implicit conversion of String into Hash when extracting json fields from AWS WAF logs with filebeat
I'm retrieving logs from AWS WAF in S3 on elasticsearch with logstash and filebeat with the following configuration :
  processors:
    - add_host_metadata:
        when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
    - add_cloud_metadata: ~
    - add_docker_metadata:
        host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        target: "json"

I then use logstash to put each header value in a different field. Here's my full logstash filter :
filter {
   if ([aws][s3][object][key]){
        if "my-waf" in [aws][s3][bucket][name] {
            grok {
                match => { "[aws][s3][bucket][name]" => "%{GREEDYDATA:servicename}"}
            }
            date { 
                match => [ "[json][timestamp]", "UNIX_MS" ]
            }
            if ([json][httpRequest][headers]){
                ruby { 
                    code => ' 
                        event.get("[json][httpRequest][headers]").each { |a| 
                            name = a["name"]
                            value = a["value"]
                            event.set("[json][httpRequest][headersFlattened][#{name}]", value)
                        } 
                    ' 
                }
            }
        } 
    mutate {
        rename => {
            "servicename" => "[service][name]"
        }
    }
}

Now, i'd like to extract the fields from the log's json and put the field at the root of the document :
  processors:
    - add_host_metadata:
        when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
    - add_cloud_metadata: ~
    - add_docker_metadata:
        host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
    - decode_json_fields:
        fields: ["message"]
        target: ''

I modify the logstash filter accordingly (even so it still makes the same error if I delete this entire part) :
date { 
    match => [ "[timestamp]", "UNIX_MS" ]
}
if ([httpRequest][headers]){
    ruby { 
        code => ' 
            event.get("[httpRequest][headers]").each { |a| 
                name = a["name"]
                value = a["value"]
                event.set("[httpRequest][headersFlattened][#{name}]", value)
            } 
        ' 
    }
}

And now I have the following error on logstash, which I did not have when the json fields were not extracted at the root of the document :
[2024-06-06T07:33:39,035][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler][main][3de0d69f427460aef4da30cf326fa3108ef7e08a9518d98711813b321a0d15fa] [local: XXXX, remote: XXXXX] Handling exception: org.jruby.exceptions.TypeError: (TypeError) no implicit conversion of String into Hash (caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.NoMethodError: (NoMethodError) undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass) [2024-06-06T07:33:39,036][WARN ][io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline][main][3de0d69f427460aef4da30cf326fa3108ef7e08a9518d98711813b321a0d15fa] An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception. org.jruby.exceptions.TypeError: (TypeError) no implicit conversion of String into Hash
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.merge!(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:2097) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.merge(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:2129) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_beats_minus_6_dot_6_dot_3_minus_java.lib.logstash.inputs.beats.decoded_event_transform.transform(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.6.3-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats/decoded_event_transform.rb:16) ~[?:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyHash.each(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1587) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.java.proxies.MapJavaProxy.each(org/jruby/java/proxies/MapJavaProxy.java:587) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_beats_minus_6_dot_6_dot_3_minus_java.lib.logstash.inputs.beats.decoded_event_transform.transform(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.6.3-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats/decoded_event_transform.rb:12) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_beats_minus_6_dot_6_dot_3_minus_java.lib.logstash.inputs.beats.codec_callback_listener.process_event(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.6.3-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats/codec_callback_listener.rb:22) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_beats_minus_6_dot_6_dot_3_minus_java.lib.logstash.inputs.beats.patch.accept(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.6.3-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats/patch.rb:10) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_codec_minus_plain_minus_3_dot_1_dot_0.lib.logstash.codecs.plain.decode(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-codec-plain-3.1.0/lib/logstash/codecs/plain.rb:54) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_beats_minus_6_dot_6_dot_3_minus_java.lib.logstash.inputs.beats.patch.accept(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.6.3-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats/patch.rb:9) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.jruby.lib.ruby.stdlib.delegate.method_missing(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/stdlib/delegate.rb:87) ~[?:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$3_dot_1_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_beats_minus_6_dot_6_dot_3_minus_java.lib.logstash.inputs.beats.message_listener.onNewMessage(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.6.3-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats/message_listener.rb:52) ~[?:?] Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.NoMethodError: (NoMethodError) undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass
        ... 1 more


This has nothing to do with your filter configuration. The logstash beats input is throwing an exception here, when it tries to decode the incoming event. Try replacing the logstash output with a file codec and look at the differences between the two events.

@Badger I've looked at the two events as you suggested and I'm not able to see much difference except for the fact that the extracted fields are under a "json" field for the first event. I'm not really familiar with ruby. Do you have maybe some ideas of what I should look for ?
